# How do I set the text of a GtkLabel from a function via its pointer?

Tags: c, gtk, label

I am having trouble setting the text of a `GtkLabel` out of the function in which it was declared. In the land of Coding Examples, my program would look something like this:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     GtkLabel *label;
     label = gtk_label_new(NULL);

     /* This works */
     gtk_label_set_text(label, "Hello!");

     /* This doesn't */
     sayHello(&label);

     return 0;
 }

 void sayHello(GtkLabel *label) {
     gtk_label_set_text(label, "Hello!");
 }
```

When `sayHello` attempts to set the label text, GTK says the following:

```
 Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_label_set_text: assertion `GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
```

How is it not a `GtkLabel`? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` is a `GtkLabel *` already.

Applying the `&` operator to it yields a pointer to a pointer, a `GtkLabel **` which is the wrong type.

You should have got some warnings about calling `sayHello` with the wrong type of argument, or implicit declaration of `sayHello` if you didn't declare it before calling it.

Comment: hehe... I have my warnings muted in my Makefile temporarily. I'll remember to check next time.